# How to fix the catchable fatal error in woocommerce?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting catchable fatal error in bellissima themeforest woocommerce theme.http://www.pursesgalore.com.au/ can anyone help on this?

Code:

```
    if(!$dst_h) :

        //can't resize, so return original url

        $img_url = $url;

        $dst_w = $orig_w;

        $dst_h = $orig_h;
```

--------------------------line number 1040 -----------------------

```
    else :

        //else check if cache exists

        if(file_exists($destfilename) && getimagesize($destfilename)) {

            $img_url = "{$upload_url}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";

        }
```

Error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/pursesga/public_html/wp-content/themes/bellissima/functions.php on line 1040

Comment: Show the code, not url.

Comment: if(!$dst_h) :

   //can't resize, so return original url

   $img_url = $url;

   $dst_w = $orig_w;

   $dst_h = $orig_h;



  else :

   //else check if cache exists

   if(file_exists($destfilename) && getimagesize($destfilename)) {

    $img_url = "{$upload_url}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";

   }

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/pursesga/public_html/wp-content/themes/bellissima/functions.php on line 1040

Comment: I have put the code and error.

Comment: add this code in the question and let me know that which is the line number 1040.

Comment: Ji can you please look at this.

Comment: `$destfilename` doesn't look like a string/file path. it looks like `WP_Error` object.